# How to program in Unity a fade transition between sprites?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I have an animation in 4 PNG images. I want to have the frames played through over the course of 1/2 second in the order 1-2-3-4-2-1 with transparency transitions.

What I wrote was supposed to have the first frame appear immediately when the parent object holding the different sprites is generated, then have it turn transparent over 1/12 of a second while the second frame turns opaque, and so forth until the last frame ends its transparent-opaque-transparent cycle.

It's probably not the most efficient way, but I made a prefab of en empty object under which are placed the 6 sprite-frames, with each sprite given an individual script.

I'm posting the first three scripts as an example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Frame1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer thisSprite;
    private Color alpha;
    private float timer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        alpha.a = 255;
        thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
        alpha.a -= timer * 3060;
        thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
        if (timer >= 1/12)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Frame2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer thisSprite;
    private Color alpha;
    private float timer;
    private int direction;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        alpha.a = 0;
        thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
            alpha.a += timer * 3060;
            thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
            if (timer >= 1/12)
            {
                direction = 1;
            }
        }
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            timer = timer - Time.deltaTime;
            alpha.a += timer * 3060;
            thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
            if (timer >= 1/6)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Frame3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer thisSprite;
    private Color alpha;
    private float timer;
    private int direction;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        alpha.a = 0;
        thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
        timer -= 1 / 12;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
            alpha.a += timer * 3060;
            thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
            if (timer >= 1 / 12)
            {
                direction = 1;
            }
        }
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            timer = timer - Time.deltaTime;
            alpha.a += timer * 3060;
            thisSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = alpha;
            if (timer >= 1 / 6)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

They all seem to be visible the moment they are generated, and they don't fade away or even get destroyed at all. What is the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need a completely different method to do this. Create an animation that simulates those perfectly using a Sprite sheet. Put the animation in an animator controller, attach it to the object and you must only have 1 script for the object which starts the animation (you set its trigger using Animator Controller conditions).. I don't have time to give a full answer yet, but if nobody does, I'll do it a bit later on

Comment: I'll check if I understand the method from your current answer... But what is wrong with my method? Let's just say I have a set of different objects that I want to have alpha values which vary over time. How do you tell them to do that? From what I gathered the lines are wrote should modify the alpha value of the object.

Comment: The method seems really weird to me and I've never used anything like it, thus I can't answer that - instead, I can point you to the best practices :) Imagine if you'd have lots of sprites and you want to animate all of them differently. Sprite sheets and animations would be the way to go. This is why I didn't post an answer, I have no idea how to fix your problem, instead I can explain the right way to do it - maybe someone will answer though :)

Comment: Sprite sheet is a single PNG image that has the different frames placed in a matrix, yes? Can't you do the method you're thinking of using separate PNG frames?

Comment: Oh, wait. If I understand correctly you meant that I should animate the fade into the PNG? I want to avoid that as that creates many more PNG data that I think shouldn't be necessary. The frames I'm animating are quite high-res, so making 30 of them (for 1/2 at 60fps) to animate 4 key frames seems inefficient.

Comment: It's actually surprising how fluid the animations seem even with 4-5 different PNGs.

Comment: But you referred to creating extra PNG frames in advance for the transitions, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210935/discussion-between-eric-and-tlso).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, using animations is a viable alternative. However, your code will not work simply because alpha accepts a value from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 255.
So simply adjust your logic to fade from 1 down to 0 and you should see your fade transitions.

Comment: I understood that eventually, and the first issue was actually that I didn't word the GetComponent part correctly so it didn't interact with the script-holding object, but now for some reason while the sprites now do show up and disappear, it doesn't do that in the correct timing. They exist for a fraction of a second, and I don't understand why.